# 冪乗計算を高速に行うには？

Tags: ruby, python, アルゴリズム

a を整数、n を自然数とします。
一般に a^n の計算を高速に行う方法を教えてください。

なお、この質問は
「特定の n に対して最小の計算回数を求める」
という趣旨の質問ではありません。

（追記）
バイナリ法によるコード（Ruby版およびPython版）を
回答に載せました。

Comment: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%86%AA%E4%B9%97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Ruby 2.2)
以下のような
①バイナリ法の上位桁から計算する方式+再帰
②バイナリ法の上位桁から計算する方式
と
③その三進法バージョン
を比較しましたが、①②に比べて③は遅い感じです。

バイナリ法＋再帰

```
a = 5
n = 10 ** 5

def power2(a, n)
  return 1 if n == 0
  k = power2(a, n >> 1)
  k *= k
  return k if n & 1 == 0
  return k * a
end

sum = 0
(0..n).each{|i|
  sum += power2(a, i)
}
p sum == a ** (n + 1) / (a - 1)
```

バイナリ法

```
a = 5
n = 10 ** 5

def power2(a, n)
  p = 1
  n.to_s(2).split('').each{|i|
    p *= p
    if i == '1'
      p *= a
    end
  }
  p
end

sum = 0
(0..n).each{|i|
  sum += power2(a, i)
}
p sum == a ** (n + 1) / (a - 1)
```

三進法バージョン

```
a = 5
n = 10 ** 5

def power3(a, n)
  p = 1
  n.to_s(3).split('').each{|i|
    p *= p * p
    if i == '1'
      p *= a
    elsif i == '2'
      p *= a * a
    end
  }
  p
end

sum = 0
(0..n).each{|i|
  sum += power3(a, i)
}
p sum == a ** (n + 1) / (a - 1)
```

(Python 2.7)
同じ計算をさせたのですが、Ruby 2.2よりずっと遅い。
ちなみに、組み込み関数
pow(http://docs.python.jp/2/library/functions.html#pow)
を使っても同じくらい遅い。

バイナリ法

```
a = 5
n = 10 ** 5

def power2(a, n):
    p = 1
    for i in list(format (n, 'b')):
        p *= p
        if i == '1':
            p *= a
    return p

sum = sum(power2(a, i) for i in xrange(n + 1))
print sum == a ** (n + 1) / (a - 1)
```

powを用いた計算

```
a = 5
n = 10 ** 5

sum = sum(pow(a, i) for i in xrange(n + 1))
print sum == a ** (n + 1) / (a - 1)
```

Comment: 測定したわけではありませんが演算そのものよりも文字列処理の方に時間を要している気がします。つまりこの質問は効率の良いbig integerライブラリを探すという問題になりませんか？

Answer (score 1):

[image: 冪乗]

◆参考コード（C言語）

```
int power(int x, int y, bool *of) {
    long long a = x;
    long long b = y;

    *of = true;
    if (b < 0) return 0;

    long long int hi = 0x7fffffffULL;
    long long int lo = ~(hi + 1) + 1;
    long long sum = 1;

    while (b != 0) {
        sum = ((b & 1) == 0) ? sum : a * sum;
        a = a * a;
        b >>= 1;
    }

    // check overflow
    if ((sum > hi) || (sum < lo)) {
        *of = true;
    }
    else {
        *of = false;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

以上です。