# バイナリ法を用いた多項式の累乗計算について

Tags: ruby, python, アルゴリズム

以前した質問 "[冪乗計算を高速に行うには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/10006)" の多項式版についての質問です。

次のように「（バイナリ法を用いた）多項式の累乗計算」を行うコードを
Ruby 2.2 および Python 2.7 で作成し、それぞれ (1 + x)^n を計算させたのですが、
Python 2.7版の方が n が34以上で結果がおかしくなってしまいました。
どのように直せばよいか教えていただけないでしょうか？

(Ruby 2.2)

```
# (f_ary×b_ary)のm次以下を取り出す
def mul(f_ary, b_ary, m)
  s1, s2 = f_ary.size, b_ary.size
  ary = Array.new(s1 + s2 - 1, 0)
  s10 = [s1 - 1, m].min
  (0..s10).each{|i|
    s20 = [s2 - 1, m - i].min
    (0..s20).each{|j|
      ary[i + j] += f_ary[i] * b_ary[j]
    }
  }
  ary
end

# ary^nのm次以下を取り出す
def power(ary, n, m)
  return [1] if n == 0
  k = power(ary, n >> 1, m)
  k = mul(k, k, m)
  return k if n & 1 == 0
  return mul(k, ary, m)
end

f0 = [1, 1]
p power(f0, 33, 33)
p power(f0, 34, 34)
```

出力結果:

```
[1, 33, 528, 5456, 40920, 237336, 1107568, 4272048, 13884156, 38567100, 92561040
, 193536720, 354817320, 573166440, 818809200, 1037158320, 1166803110, 1166803110
, 1037158320, 818809200, 573166440, 354817320, 193536720, 92561040, 38567100, 13
884156, 4272048, 1107568, 237336, 40920, 5456, 528, 33, 1]
[1, 34, 561, 5984, 46376, 278256, 1344904, 5379616, 18156204, 52451256, 13112814
0, 286097760, 548354040, 927983760, 1391975640, 1855967520, 2203961430, 23336062
20, 2203961430, 1855967520, 1391975640, 927983760, 548354040, 286097760, 1311281
40, 52451256, 18156204, 5379616, 1344904, 278256, 46376, 5984, 561, 34, 1]
```

(Python 2.7)
NumPyを使っています。

```
import numpy

def power(f, n):
    p = numpy.poly1d([1])
    for i in list(format (n, 'b')):
        p *= p
        if i == '1':
            p *= f
    return p

f0 = numpy.poly1d([1, 1])
print list(reversed((power(f0, 33)).c))
print list(reversed((power(f0, 34)).c))
```

出力結果:

```
[1, 33, 528, 5456, 40920, 237336, 1107568, 4272048, 13884156, 38567100, 92561040
, 193536720, 354817320, 573166440, 818809200, 1037158320, 1166803110, 1166803110
, 1037158320, 818809200, 573166440, 354817320, 193536720, 92561040, 38567100, 13
884156, 4272048, 1107568, 237336, 40920, 5456, 528, 33, 1]
[1, 34, 561, 5984, 46376, 278256, 1344904, 5379616, 18156204, 52451256, 13112814
0, 286097760, 548354040, 927983760, 1391975640, 1855967520, -2091005866, -196136
1076, -2091005866, 1855967520, 1391975640, 927983760, 548354040, 286097760, 1311
28140, 52451256, 18156204, 5379616, 1344904, 278256, 46376, 5984, 561, 34, 1]
```

（追記）
次のようにバイナリ法を用いずとも全く同じ問題が発生している。

```
import numpy

def power(f, n):
    i = 1
    p = f
    while i < n:
        p *= f
        i += 1
    return p

f0 = numpy.poly1d([1, 1])
print list(reversed((power(f0, 33)).c))
print list(reversed((power(f0, 34)).c))
```

出力結果:
質問のPython 2.7版の出力結果と同じ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

numpy では、整数は C などと同じフォーマットで格納されているので、桁あふれを起こしているのでしょう。20億を越えたあたりでおかしくなっているので、32bitの符号付き整数だとすると辻褄が合います。ただ、手元の Linux Mint で試したところ、64bitのためか、問題が再現しませんでした。

試しに

```
import numpy

def power(f, n):
    p = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([1], dtype=numpy.int64))
    for i in format (n, 'b'):
        p *= p
        if i == '1':
            p *= f
    return p

f0 = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([1, 1], dtype=numpy.int64))
print list(reversed((power(f0, 33)).c))
print list(reversed((power(f0, 34)).c))
```

などと、データ型を指定してみたら、どうでしょうか。

Comment: おっしゃるとおり、データ型を指定すると問題が解決しました。