# Numpyを使ってより大きな累乗計算をさせるには？

Tags: python

以前した質問（[（バイナリ法を用いた）多項式の累乗計算について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12910/%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AA%E6%B3%95%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F-%E5%A4%9A%E9%A0%85%E5%BC%8F%E3%81%AE%E7%B4%AF%E4%B9%97%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/12917#12917)）の続きの質問です。

以前の質問で、
「データ型を指定することで、より大きな累乗計算をできる」
ことがわかりました。
それでは、どこまで累乗計算ができるか気になり、次のコードを実行しました。

```
# -*- coding: cp932 -*-
import numpy

# m次以下のみにする
def mth_degree_poly(p, m):
    return numpy.poly1d(list(p)[- m - 1:])

def power(f, n, m, type):
    p = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([1], dtype = type))
    for i in format (n, 'b'):
        p *= p
        p = mth_degree_poly(p, m)
        if i == '1':
            p *= f
            p = mth_degree_poly(p, m)
    return p

# int64型
type = numpy.int64
f0 = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([4, 3, 2, 1], dtype = type))
print list(reversed((power(f0, 20, 20 * 3, type)).c))
print list(reversed((power(f0, 21, 21 * 3, type)).c))
# データ型指定なし
type = None
f1 = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([4, 3, 2, 1]))
print list(reversed((power(f1, 10, 10 * 3, type)).c))
print list(reversed((power(f1, 11, 11 * 3, type)).c))
# object型
type = numpy.object
f2 = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([4, 3, 2, 1], dtype = type))
print list(reversed((power(f2, 11, 11 * 3, type)).c))
print list(reversed((power(f2, 12, 12 * 3, type)).c))
```

その結果、
「上記計算では、データ型が
　int64型だと20乗まで、
　指定なしだと（私の環境では）10乗まで、
　object型だと11乗まで
　しか正確に計算できない」
ことがわかりました。

Numpyでは、
「N > 20 なる整数に対し、
　(1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3)^N
　の計算はできない」
のでしょうか？
それとも、上記コードでは工夫が足りないということでしょうか？

Comment: `type = numpy.object;f2 = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([4, 3, 2, 1], dtype = type))` の部分の array を `numpy.array([4L, 3L, 2L, 1L], dtype=typ)` としてみて下さい(`L`(long) suffix を追加)。これで多倍長計算ができる様になります。

Comment: N　= 21 のときはうまくいくのですが、N = 22 とすると、負の数が出てきておかしくなるのはなぜでしょう？

Comment: `def mth_degree_poly(p, m): return numpy.poly1d(list(p)[- m - 1:])` => `numpy.poly1d(numpy.array(list(p)[- m - 1:], dtype = numpy.object))`, `p = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([1], dtype = type))` => `p = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([1L], dtype = type))` にする必要があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問のコードでは工夫が足りなかったようです。
argus さんのコメントに従い、以下のように変更。

```
# -*- coding: cp932 -*-
import numpy

# m次以下のみにする
def mth_degree_poly(p, m, type):
    return numpy.poly1d(numpy.array(list(p)[- m - 1:], dtype = type))

def power(f, n, m, type):
    p = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([1L], dtype = type))
    for i in format (n, 'b'):
        p *= p
        p = mth_degree_poly(p, m, type)
        if i == '1':
            p *= f
            p = mth_degree_poly(p, m, type)
    return p

type = numpy.object
f2 = numpy.poly1d(numpy.array([4L, 3L, 2L, 1L], dtype = type))
print list(reversed((power(f2, 50, 50 * 3, type)).c))
```